# "jwt" gem may have a .decode() issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I'm attempting to use the `jwt` gem with my API-only Rails app and I'm following this guide:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api

I can call the `/authenticate` endpoint and it gives me a valid token. My issue is when I try to call a function protected by `before_action :authenticate_request` it seems to fail at the point where `JsonWebToken.decode()` is called.

I can verify the token being passed is valid, and I can verify the secret passphrase is what I want to use, and I get valid JSON back for `body`.  So at this point it seems there's an issue with how the gem runs, but it seems nothing happens when I run `HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(body)`. Because it throws no internal exceptions I don't know exactly what's failing inside.

All useful suggestions appreciated,

- Joe

Comment: I'm using Jwt for Ruby in several API services and never had such issue. Would you post here the actual generated token as well as the secret passphrase? Also, which version of Rails and Jwt are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good bit tracing tonight, turns out the problem was THIS GUY.

In the link I referenced earlier, the example files are very close to production-ready, but there's some customization/tweaking that needs to be done. I noticed in `authenticate_user.rb`, I had to provide an email and password and replace the generic `User` class with my own class (in `.user()`); I updated that and was able to log in and that was that - or so I thought... I wasn't able to get the API to return a valid token in my response header. In a case of tl;dr, it turns out I also needed to make the same customization and replace `User` in `authorize_api_request.rb` as well (in `.user()`).

Thank you for your attention. I hope this insight saves others a bit of trouble.